# Error at FTP Task: Failed to lock variable SSIS

Tags: ftp, ssis

I am trying to FTP receive multiple files *.txt from a remote server's root directory.

I have defined the following variables

remotePath = /

localPath = c:\downloads

fileMask = *.txt

In the FTP Task editor, I have created expression for remotePath, as in

remotePath = @[User::remotePath] +  @[User::fileMask] which evaluates correctly to /*.txt

I have set IsRemotePathVariable to True.

IsLocalPathVariable to True

LocalVariable to User::localPath

When I run this package, I am getting an error.

Error at FTP Task: Failed to lock variable "/*.txt" for read access with error ....

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but may help someone else:
I had the MessageSource set in both the Email and Expression settings
I fixed it by removing the Mail setting and change the type to Direct Input.