# MessageSource expression - Failed to lock variable

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I'm attempting to use the send-mail task to send a message upon the successful completion of a data-flow task.

When the package is executed, an error is generated:

> Error: Failed to lock variable "The extraction was
>   successful.
>
> ### PROPERTIES
>
> Starting: 10/27/2015 Ending: 10/27/2015 11:59:59 PM Records: 207 " for
>   read access with error 0xC0010001 "The variable cannot be found. This
>   occurs when an attempt is made to retrieve a variable from the
>   Variables collection on a container during execution of the package,
>   and the variable is not there. The variable name may have changed or
>   the variable is not being created.".

The send-mail task's `MessageSourceType` is set to `Variable`.

The expression assigned to the send-mail task's `MessageSource` property:

```
"The extraction was successful.\n\n" +
"PROPERTIES\n" +
"----------\n\n" +
"Starting: " + (DT_WSTR, 50) @[$Project::StartingDateTime] + "\n" + 
"Ending: " + (DT_WSTR, 50)  @[$Project::EndingDatetime] + "\n" + 
"Records: " + (DT_WSTR, 50) @[User::OriginalRecords] + "\n"
```

The `User::OriginalRecords` variable is being (correctly) populated by a row-count task.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to access the variable somewhere in the data flow, like a script component task?

Comment: The `User::OriginalRecords` is set in a data flow, but not used there (in a script component).

Answer (score 3):

I need to set the send-mail task's MessageSourceType is set to `Direct Input`.  [Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26663752/134367).